# Popup window - different size in Safari to other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I am using the following code to popup a window - it needs to be an exact size - and it is in every browser except Safari.

You can test this directly with the following 2 pages. The first creates a page with a link to click to popup the window. The second is the page that is opened that has an alert with the page size.

In Safari Mac it shows the dimensions: 800 x 578 - in every other browser its 800 x 640 (which it should be).

Page with link:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="size.html" onclick="javascript:void window.open('size.html','1401806967791','width=800,height=640,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');return false;">PacFace</a>

<br />
<a href="#size.html" onClick="window.open('size.html','pagename','resizable,height=640,width=800'); return false;">New Page</a>

</body>
</html>
```

..and size.html:

```
<html>
<script>
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

alert(w + ' × ' + h);

</script>
</html>
```

Two links are present - on both cases it opens a new window - at the wrong height (width is fine) - on safari only.

How can I get it to popup a new window at the same size across all browsers?

I have researched this a lot and strangely not found anything on this specific subject.

Comment: why are you declaring `var w` twice?

Comment: sorry fixed that - you may need to refresh the loaded page to get the correct figures - but you get the idea.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is because you are setting the "outer" height, since safari has different size borders it would make sense that the inner size would be different.

Comment: ok - how can I fix that?

Comment: (not the width is perfect - 800 - it is only height thats wrong, kind of looks like its something to do with the address bar - which is fixable - but then it is in Chrome too and chrome works fine)

Comment: I bet if you check the outer height it will match your `640px` if it does, we can write some more javascript :)

Comment: yep you're right! How can I set the innerHeight instead?

Comment: Ok i would write some javascript that says, if inner height is less then 640px, set outer with to outterheight + (outterheight - innerheight). If you need help with it, I can write it up, but I cannot test it since I don't have IOS.

Comment: Thanks - it's MacOS - but I guess you don't have that too. Would be helpful if you could write it thanks - it does sound like a bit of a hack, i guess there's no way to jus open windows with the same inner height initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there might be  some syntax errors here, but like I said in the comments, I cannot test it. Try this:

```
function setWindowHeight(){
            var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
            var outerHeight = window.outerHeight;
            var newHeight;
            if (windowHeight < 640) {
                newHeight = outerHeight + (outerHeight - windowHeight);
                document.getElementById('YourIdHere').style.height = newHeight + "px";
            }
        }
```

Since IOS has different size borders, you will need to compensate for them, there might be a better way out there to do it, but this should get the job done.